# Camera that transfers photos via Bluetooth

Tags: point-and-shoot, wireless

I'm looking for a point and shoot digital camera (or adapter card like Eye-Fi) that can transfer photos via Bluetooth.

(I'm specifically interested in Bluetooth because the Wi-Fi adapter on my laptop will be busy)

Comment: You're wi-fi adapter should be able to handle more than one connection at once. You can surf the web and transfer photos at the same time, for example.

Comment: <slaps self> I mean your not you're!

Comment: Wi-Fi has a *lot* more bandwidth that Bluetooth, so even when it's "busy", it will usually have more bandwidth available than Bluetooth has total (BT=1 Mbps, 802.11g = 54 Mbps).

Comment: Maybe the laptop is connected to a WiFi network that requires a password, and the Eye-Fi card is not configured to join that network?

Comment: AGAIN, this is my situation.  I know that Wi-Fi is typically a better solution and that it has more bandwidth.  I'm still interested in Bluetooth.  @ElendilTheTall Do you know how to do this?  I was under the impression that most operating systems out of the box can only connect to one wireless network per wireless adapter (and I only have one)

Comment: You configure the EyeFi to connect to the same network as your laptop.

Comment: @Imre That involves using the computer to configure the card for each network you want to use, right? I can see BT being a more convenient solution for some people. I think it's a reasonable question, even if the answer is that no such camera exists.

Comment: @Imre My laptop will be connected to a public or tethered network that the camera cannot connect to

Comment: Also: The WiFi network could use MAC address filtering that prevents the Eye-Fi from connecting, or the WiFi network could be a "pay-to-use" network that he doesn't want to pay twice for (or that he can't connect to without a web browser). (Yep, he just confirmed that something like this is the case.)

Comment: What wi-fi network will you be connecting to? Eye-Fi Pro X2 cards can connect through AT&T public access points (Starbucks etc). And the Mobile X2 uploads direct to iOS or Android devices without the need for a wi-fi network, if that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While there aren't a *ton* of cameras out there with bluetooth support, here are a few I found which you may want to look into:

- [Samsung ST1000](http://www.samsungimaging.net/2009/10/07/finding-myself-with-the-gps-samsung-digital-imaging-st1000cl65/)
- [Samsung CL65](http://www.engadget.com/2009/08/13/samsung-crams-wifi-gps-and-bluetooth-2-0-into-well-specced-cl65/)
- [Kodak EasySshare V610](http://www.dpreview.com/reviews/kodakv610/)

Now all of these cameras are a little 'long in the tooth,' and I haven't used any of them... This was just me and Google coming up with some options.

I also found an interesting accessory for Olympus cameras called the '[PENpal](http://www.geeky-gadgets.com/olympus-penpal-sends-photos-via-bluetooth-11-01-2011/)' (unfortunate name, IMO). Apparently it attaches to any appropriately equipped Olympus camera and adds bluetooth transfer capabilities. Might be worth checking out...

There has been some [minor speculation](http://www.ismashphone.com/2011/01/why-fi-new-eye-fi-cards-promise-to-cut-the-cordless.html) on 'teh interwebs' regarding an upcoming EyeFi bluetooth release, but at this point I'd have a hard time characterizing them as more than rumors, so I wouldn't count on anything appearing *soon*.

Anyway, there's a few links to help your research along.

Comment: I have the ST1000, and from what i can gather, the CL65 is the same camera, just in US form... It is a manual task to send photos via either Wifi or Bluetooth on the Samsung... I have found it can be quicker to just plug in the device... Especially given that bluetooth has limited speed...

Answer (score 4):

If you are unable to find a Bluetooth solution, and you cannot connect the Eye-Fi to the same WiFi network that the computer is using, one alternative would be to purchase a USB WiFi adapter for the computer, to provide a second WiFi interface. You can use the second WiFi interface to [communicate with certain models of Eye-Fi in Ad Hoc mode](http://support.eye.fi/product-info/specs-details/setup-requirements/does-the-eye-fi-card-support-ad-hoc-wi-fi-2/).

Comment: Good idea.  That would free me up to use any camera with an SD card.

Answer (score 2):

[Samsug CL80](http://gizmodo.com/#!5441536/samsung-cl80-a-point+and+shoot-crammed-with-14-megapixels-wi+fi-and-amoled-touchscreen) (ST5500 in Europe) is a model of spring 2010 providing bluetooth connectivity. It resizes pictures down to 1024x768 when sending over Bluetooth to fight the slow transfer (and bluetooth IS slow).